# reordering datable will mix values

Tags: javascript, datatables

I work wit [DataTables](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/restrictedOrdering.html) and would like to realize drag and drop reordering.
My Code a the moment:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                      <table id="tablePositionen" class="table table-lg hover table-striped">
                          <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>Bezeichnung</th>
                              <th>Menge</th>
                              <th>Preis</th>
                              <th>Gesamt</th>
                              <th class="text-right"></th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td>Article 1</td>
                                  <td>1,00</td>
                                  <td>10,00 €</td>
                                  <td>10,00 €</td>
                                  <td class="text-right">
                                      <div class="dropdown">
                                          <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm btn-floating"
                                             data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                          </a>
                                          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Bearbeiten</button>
                                              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Löschen</button>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                    <td>Article 2</td>
                                    <td>2,00</td>
                                    <td>56,00 €</td>
                                    <td>56,00 €</td>
                                    <td class="text-right">
                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm btn-floating"
                                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                              <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Bearbeiten</button>
                                                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Löschen</button>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var tablePositionen = $('#tablePositionen').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [0], orderable: true, className: 'reorder' },
            { targets: '_all', orderable: false }
        ],
        "ordering": false,
        "paging": false,
        rowReorder: true,
        "lengthMenu": [[10], [10]],
        "language": {
            "url": "https:////cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
        }
    });
```

My Table looks like this:

[image]

And If now drag and drop the second row above the first row, the other columns values will not be the correct one:

[image]

Where is my mistake??

Comment: table-responsive, is it from bootstrap? or somewhere else?

Comment: have you tried setting ordering as true?

Comment: If you can see, the first column "Bezeichnung" will be sorted. but the other column values stay on old position.

Comment: I don't know which framework you are using, but you can get the event, reordering them, get the new order, updating the list with the new order, and then start again. If you are using a particular framework or ui components, maybe there is a tool for this that does it for you

Comment: I don't understand your question. I am using the basic DataTables:  https://datatables.net

Comment: have you check on support? there is a link on that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes I made to resolve your issue:

(1) Added a "sequence" column as the first column in the table.

(2) Changed the DataTable initialization options to hide that sequence column, and, instead, allow the user to perform a drag from anywhere in a row (as opposed to the default location which is the first column only).

(3) Removed the remaining unneeded options (although you can add back anything you need such as `"paging": false`). Note that some options contradicted each other, such as `paging` and `lengthMenu`.

(4) Made a minor change to the language URL (too many forward slashes). This is not relevant to the drag/drop issue.

Here is the result:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var tablePositionen = $('#tablePositionen').DataTable({
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'tr'
        },
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: 0, visible: false }
        ],
        "language": {
            "url": "https:////cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
        }
    });
} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <!-- row reorder -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.8/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.8/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css"/> 

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="tablePositionen" class="table table-lg hover table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Seq.</th>
      <th>Bezeichnung</th>
      <th>Menge</th>
      <th>Preis</th>
      <th>Gesamt</th>
      <th class="text-right"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Article 1</td>
          <td>1,00</td>
          <td>10,00 €</td>
          <td>10,00 €</td>
          <td class="text-right">
              <div class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm btn-floating"
                     data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Bearbeiten</button>
                      <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Löschen</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Article 2</td>
            <td>2,00</td>
            <td>56,00 €</td>
            <td>56,00 €</td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm btn-floating"
                       data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Bearbeiten</button>
                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Löschen</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Just to add: All of the row reorder [examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/) use an initial column to support reordering (the `Seq.` column I added). This is required - although I don't recall seeing this explicitly mentioned in the documentation. For your case, I chose to hide this initial (but required) column, and use the "full row" drag option.